# How to focus on new tab?

Tags: qt4

I was able to add a new tab using
qtabwidget->addTab ( newtab, title );

But is it possible to focus on this
tab in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> 'setCurrentWidget' or 'setCurrentIndex' will do the job.

You can use either the pointer to the added widget or a numeric index.

See:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCurrentWidget

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex-prop

For example, if you have a tab widget with say 3 tabs, you can focus on the 2nd tab like this:

```
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

If you just want to use the pointer to your widget (MyWidget of type QWidget) then here is another example:

```
MyWidget* pointerToMyWidgetInTab = new MyWidget();
ui->tabWidget->addTab(pointerToMyWidgetInTab,"Tab2")
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(pointerToMyWidgetInTab2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the total number of tabs and set the last one:

```
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(ui->tabWidget->count()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
private slots:
void setFocusAddedTab();
void on_addTabButton(); //Add Button
```

.cpp

```
void MainWindow::setFocusAddedTab() {
int x = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex()+1;
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(x)
   }

void MainWindow::on_addTabButton() {
ui->tabWidget->addTab(...,...);
setFocusAddedTab();
}
```